# curl_init php não funciona em url amigável?

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou fazendo uns testes com curl_init php

Acontece que tenho os links assim:

```
http://localhost/produto/novo
```

Internamente ele acessa o arquivo novo.php, mas estou usando htaccess para trabalhar com URLs amigaveis

Preciso fazer um arquivo que ira aceitar consultas via curl_init do php que está em outro servidor

Se eu abrir o navegador e digitar:

```
http://localhost/produto/novo?codigo=1
```

Ele aceita beleza, ou seja, a pagina esta operando normalmente e aceitando os parametros.

Mas se eu uso essa mesma URL no curl_init ele não aceita, ele me traz o conteudo da index.

Agora se eu coloco a url com o nome do arquivo ele aceita:

```
$url = http://localhost/produto/novo.php
```

o curl_init só acessa arquivos diretamente, não da pra usar url amigaveis nele?

Minha requisição:

```
    ...
    $dados = array("pedidos" => $pedidos, "status" => $status, "loja" => $loja);


    $url = "http://123.123.123.123/recebe.transito.php"; 
    AQUI EU GOSTARIA DE COLOCAR A URL AMIGAVEL
    $url = "http://123.123.123.123/recebe.transito"; // SEM O .PHP
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    //$res = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // Pegar o código de resposta

    $result = json_decode($res);
....
```

Meu .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: poste seu .htaccess

Comment: Você precisa postar o código do seu `htaccess` e o código da sua requisição `curl`, se não as respostas vão ficar muito 'especulativas'

Comment: "Preciso fazer um arquivo que ira aceitar consultas via curl_init do php que está em outro servidor". Em outro servidor ou outro arquivo/pasta? Os dois servidores estão na sua máquina rodando em portas diferentes? Elabore melhor o cenário para podermos ajudar melhor.

Comment: Apenas adiantando e respondendo sua pergunta do título: sim, o curl funciona perfeitamente com url amigável. O curl é um cliente http como o navegador. O problema deve estar na implementação.

Comment: Coloquei os códigos talvez facilite a compreensão

Comment: Uma coisa interessante, o uso de URL amigável não é um redirecionamento mas sim um "include" de arquivos, ou seja o index é responsável por exibir  o conteúdo de outros arquivos conforme a requisição, dessa forma o curl_init não deveria mostrar o conteúdo do index e sim  do include, a impressão que dá é: ou o curl_init não envia a url completa ou o php não compreende a url enviada pelo curl quando não ha um fim de arquivo como .php ou .html

Comment: Amigo, quando você diz que está exibindo o conteúdo do index.php, você quer dizer que exibe o código do index.php, e não o resultado gerado pelo mesmo? Se sim, seu problema é na configuração do seu servidor web. Você usa apache?

Comment: Não é o codigo não... é a pagina index (html)... é como se ele não entendesse que existe uma requisição em um arquivo entao ele mostra o conteudo do index.

Answer (score -1):

Por default o `curl` não segue as regras de redirect escritas no seu `.htaccess`. É necessário adicionar a flag `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` antes:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: De onde você tirou essa informação, meu jovem? Poderia adicionar essa informação? Porque, se o navegador reconhece, porque não o `Curl`?

Comment: Wallace, redirect é diferente de rewrite

Comment: Joel veja que no meu script ja tenho essa opção ativa, mas ainda não funciona